# MVC Form not able to post List of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

so I have an MVC Asp.net app that is having issues. Essentially, I have a View that contains a form, and its contents are bound to a list of objects. Within this loop, it loads PartialView's with the items being looped over. Now everything works up till the submittion of the form. When it gets submitted, the controller is sent a null list of objects. The code below demonstates the problems.

Parent View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PlanCompareViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ComparePlans", "Plans", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "compareForm" }))
{
<div>
    @foreach (var planVM in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_partialView", planVM)
    }
</div>
}
```

_partialView:

```
@model PlanCompareViewModel
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.PlanID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.CurrentPlan)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.ShouldCompare)
   <input type="submit" value="Compare"/>
</div>
```

And these are the classes for the above code:

PlanViewModel:

```
public class PlansCompareViewModel
{

    public int PlanID { get; set; }
    public Plan CurrentPlan { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldCompare { get; set; }
    public PlansCompareViewModel(Plan plan)
    {
        ShouldCompare = false;
        PlanID = plan.PlanId;
        CurrentPlan = plan;
    }

    public PlansCompareViewModel()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
    public static IEnumerable<PlansCompareViewModel> CreatePlansVM(IEnumerable<Plan> plans)
    {
        return plans.Select(p => new PlansCompareViewModel(p)).AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class PlansController : MyBaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ComparePlans(IEnumerable<PlanCompareViewModel> model)
    {
         //the model passed into here is NULL
    }
}
```

And the problem is in the controller action. As far as I am aware, it should be posting an enumerable list of PlanCompareViewModels, yet it is null. When in inspect the post data being sent, it is sending the correct params. And if I were to change 'IEnumerable' to 'FormCollection', it contains the correct values. Can anyone see why the binder is not creating the correct object? I can get around this using javascript, but that defeats the purpose! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Asp-Net-MVC-Post-List-of-Objects

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Your model is `null` because the way you're supplying the inputs to your form means the model binder has no way to distinguish between the elements.  Right now, this code:

```
@foreach (var planVM in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_partialView", planVM)
}
```

is not supplying any kind of index to those items.  So it would repeatedly generate HTML output like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="yourmodelprefix.PlanID" />
<input type="hidden" name="yourmodelprefix.CurrentPlan" />
<input type="checkbox" name="yourmodelprefix.ShouldCompare" />
```

However, as you're wanting to bind to a collection, you need your form elements to be named with an index, such as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="yourmodelprefix[0].PlanID" />
<input type="hidden" name="yourmodelprefix[0].CurrentPlan" />
<input type="checkbox" name="yourmodelprefix[0].ShouldCompare" />
<input type="hidden" name="yourmodelprefix[1].PlanID" />
<input type="hidden" name="yourmodelprefix[1].CurrentPlan" />
<input type="checkbox" name="yourmodelprefix[1].ShouldCompare" />
```

That index is what enables the model binder to associate the separate pieces of data, allowing it to construct the correct model.  So here's what I'd suggest you do to fix it.  Rather than looping over your collection, using a partial view, leverage the power of templates instead.  Here's the steps you'd need to follow:

1. Create an `EditorTemplates` folder inside your view's current folder (e.g. if your view is `Home\Index.cshtml`, create the folder `Home\EditorTemplates`).
2. Create a strongly-typed view in that directory with the name that matches your model.  In your case that would be `PlanCompareViewModel.cshtml`.

Now, everything you have in your partial view wants to go in that template:

```
@model PlanCompareViewModel
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.PlanID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.CurrentPlan)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.ShouldCompare)
   <input type="submit" value="Compare"/>
</div>
```

Finally, your parent view is simplified to this:

```
@model IEnumerable<PlanCompareViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ComparePlans", "Plans", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "compareForm" }))
{
<div>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
</div>
}
```

`DisplayTemplates` and `EditorTemplates` are smart enough to know when they are handling collections.  That means they will automatically generate the correct names, including indices, for your form elements so that you can correctly model bind to a collection.

Comment: Thanks, this answer really helped me out today.

Answer (score 37):

Please read this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx
You should set indicies for your html elements "name" attributes like `planCompareViewModel[0].PlanId`, `planCompareViewModel[1].PlanId` to make binder able to parse them into IEnumerable.
Instead of `@foreach (var planVM in Model)` use `for` loop and render names with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `EditorTemplate` did not work. How I did -

ViewModel file -

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    public class MultipleFormViewModel
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Main View (cshtml) file -

```
@model List<MultipleFormViewModel>

@{
    var list = new List<MultipleFormViewModel>();
    ViewData["index"] = 0;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDataPoint", "MultipleForm", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var dataPoint = new MultipleFormViewModel();
        list.Add(dataPoint);
        
        ViewData["index"] = i;
        @Html.Partial("_AddDataPointFormPartial", ((List<MultipleFormViewModel>)list)[i], ViewData)
        
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Save Data Points" />
}
```

Partial View (under Shared folder) file -

```
@model MultipleFormViewModel

@{
    var index = ViewData["index"];
}
<div>
    <div>
        <label>Value:</label>
        
        <input asp-for="Value" name="@("["+index+"].Value")" id="@("z"+index+"__Value")" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Title:</label>

        <input asp-for="Title" name="@("["+index+"].Title")" id="@("z"+index+"__Title")" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And Finally Controller -

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveDataPoint(List<MultipleFormViewModel> datapoints)
{
    Console.WriteLine(datapoints.Count);
    //Write your code
    return Content("hello..");
}
```