# How to receive dates from multidatespicker in a List<Datetime> ASP NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, post, jquery-multidatespicker

In my program, I have implemented multidatespicker (http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) for my solution. I have an attribute called `DatesDispo` to receive my dates picked from my calendar.

```
public List<DateTime> DatesDispo { get; set; }
```

In my razor view, I have an input for my calendar:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatesDispo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input name="DatesDispo" id="DatesDispo"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I see my calendar and until there it's working. But on post of the form, I don't receive my dates that I picked in my `DateDispo` field. In debug mode, I had tested this and it worked but maybe I changed something and now I'm unable to bind dates picked with my date field. Someone know why? I swear that I had picked 2 dates and my list of dates had a count = 2.

Edited:
Data received from post => https://gyazo.com/629a7f01c6802b2cefc825d786b2470b

> __RequestVerificationToken=FG381kMw0ANq_vV0ucoFr7Rrn6J1nqZNptlSy9JtT27JUggqOvru9Q‌​FkPZP40QniZ_ZBtpBNzMN00MZA5Aq06ZByz3yAz9-YNXpNjMhOG0o1&IdHabilete=7&Adresse=&Vill‌​e=&CodePostal=&Pays=&Province=&DateMax=2016-01-26+13%3A42%3A23&DateCreation=2016-‌​01-26+13%3A42%3A23&DatesDispo=01%2F28%2F2016%2C+01%2F29%2F2016&Specifications=Sys‌​tem.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BFavornet.Models.Biz.SpecDemande%5D
>     DatesDispo=01%2F28%2F2016%2C+01%2F29%2F2016

`DatesDispo` field extracted from above

```
DatesDispo=01%2F28%2F2016%2C+01%2F29%2F2016
```

Comment: Use a network monitor tool (in your browser's debugger or Fiddler) to watch the POST request. What does your dates look like in the request body? What does your post action signature look like?

Comment: This? https://gyazo.com/629a7f01c6802b2cefc825d786b2470b

Comment: Yes, and click _view source_ to see the raw data sent. The tool may be showing you a "friendly view" of the data. The automatic binding may have problems with the date format sent and possibly your locale setting.

Comment: __RequestVerificationToken=FG381kMw0ANq_vV0ucoFr7Rrn6J1nqZNptlSy9JtT27JUggqOvru9QFkPZP40QniZ_ZBtpBNzMN00MZA5Aq06ZByz3yAz9-YNXpNjMhOG0o1&IdHabilete=7&Adresse=&Ville=&CodePostal=&Pays=&Province=&DateMax=2016-01-26+13%3A42%3A23&DateCreation=2016-01-26+13%3A42%3A23&DatesDispo=01%2F28%2F2016%2C+01%2F29%2F2016&Specifications=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BFavornet.Models.Biz.SpecDemande%5D

Comment: Easier to see : DatesDispo=01%2F28%2F2016%2C+01%2F29%2F2016

Comment: Can you explain to me? haha I'm not sure what is the problem

Comment: I see possibly three issues: 1) The dates are sent as single string and the auto binding doesn't recognize it as a collection of dates. 2) If you [post a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964553/mvc-form-not-able-to-post-list-of-objects) you usually need an index. 3) Your machine's locale setting may have trouble parsing the date string with the format the client-side is sending mm/dd/yyyy. It will also help to see your action function.

Comment: I don't know how I did it but check this, I have 1 date in my list: https://gyazo.com/9974320fcb66b4cfa08d25ebef7ebe0c

Comment: But 2 dates is not working

Comment: You will either need to accept the dates as a comma-delimited string of dates. Then parse that string on the server back into an array of date strings. Then into a collection of DateTime objects. OR it looks like you need an index on your `DatesDispo` input(s). `<input name="DatesDispo[1]" ...>` which then leads to a new problem of generating multiple inputs dynamically.

Comment: I finally took the string and convert it to dates.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you intend to post a collection of dates. You are posting a single field as a single string. In this case the auto binding doesn't have a problem with a single date but can't recognize the way you send multiple dates.

```
<input name="DatesDispo" id="DatesDispo"></input>
```

A single input is sending as

```
DatesDispo=01%2F28%2F2016%2C+01%2F29%2F2016
```

Or

```
"01/28/2016, 01/29/2016"
```

One solution is to send it as string that needs to be parsed back into a collection.

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string DatesDispo { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendDates(SomeModel model)
{
    List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
    var datesDispo = model.DatesDispo.Split(',');

    foreach(var date in datesDispo)
    {
        dates.Add(DateTime.Parse(date));
    }

    ...
}
```