# Binding multiple records in child model to parent modelview in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a query. I want to bind multiple record to model which is inside ModelView,
That way it'll insert record as per the Id of parent model.

here is my code

```
@model PathoWebApp.ModelViews.SubTestOnes
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "SubTests", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmSubTestOnes" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NormalRange)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.NormalRangeB)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="form-group" id="divForNormalRange">
                <table class="table table-responsive" id="TestSample">
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#NormalRangeB').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SubTests/GetNormalRange',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#TestSample').each(function () {
                        var tds = '<tr>';
                        tds += data;
                        tds += '</tr>';
                        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
                        } else {
                            $(this).append(tds);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

the ajax call the partial view to get Row that have button which create multiple rows on table which looks like this.
[image: Image of view]

When I want to submit this record it selects only first Record In Model.
Please Help...

**Update**
Parent Model
*SubTestOnes*

```
public class SubTestOnes
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Test")]
        public Nullable<Int64> TestId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Sub Test")]
        public string SubTestName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Test Unit")]
        public string TestUnit { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Normal Range")]
        public string NormalRange { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Dependent Sub Test One")]
        public string DependentSubTestOne { get; set; }
        public string DependentSubTestTwo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Formula")]
        public string Formula { get; set; }
        public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Priority { get; set; }
        public string Heading { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Investigation { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool NormalRangeB { get; set; }
        public bool DependentSubTestOneB { get; set; }
        public bool DependentSubTestTwoB { get; set; }
        public bool InvestigationB { get; set; }
        public bool HeadingB { get; set; }
        public bool ValueB { get; set; }
        public List<Models.NormalRangeInfo> NormalRanges { get; set; }
    }
```

Child model
*NormalRangeInfo*

```
public class NormalRangeInfo
    {
        [Key,DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Int64 NormalRangeID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SubTests")]
        public Int64 SubtestID { get; set; }
        public int? NormalMin { get; set; }
        public int? NormalMax { get; set; }
        public string NormalType { get; set; }
        public string NormalAllowValue { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AgeMin { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AgeMax { get; set; }
        public string AgeType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Which model is the parent model? Which model is the child model? Which model is submitted? _Show us the relevant parts_ of the model definitions and strip out the bootstrap formatting so it's easier to see your form without scrolling three times.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964553/mvc-form-not-able-to-post-list-of-objects) for posting a collection. And looking at your ajax callback, make sure `data` (which you append to the table) contains a form element or the form submission will not send anything back.