# MVC Index View with EditorFor in the list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker, editorfor

In my `Index` View for the list of of rows I put a `EditorFor` instead of `DisplayFor` for my field. I am trying to capture a *Completion Date* for my rows and then have the ability to `Submit` all the rows that have a value. The field is a `DateTime` and the `DatePicker` for the fields work however, when I select a value in any row besides the first row it will change the value in the first row and does not place any value in the respective field.

[image]

Then I would like to click the Submit button and have it bring in the list and look for any Modifications to the record and record the change.

In my Index.cshtml i tried the following -

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++ )
        { 
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.CompletionDate[i])
        }
```

However it does not like `item.CompletionDate[i]`. I receive *Cannot apply index with [] to an expression of type System.DateTime?*

Update:

My model

```
namespace AQB_MON.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class PrevMaintenanceList
{
    public int PrevMaintenanceListID { get; set; }
    public int PreventativeMaintenanceID { get; set; }
    public int DeviceTypeMaintenanceID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Completion Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? CompletionDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does your Model look like? You might need instead `item[i].CompletionDate`.

Comment: When I change it to `item[i],CompletionDate` I receive the same message just on the item portion instead of on the CompletionDate portion.

Comment: What is the type of `item`? If it is a collection you can use the indexer `item[i]`. You can't do that on a property `CompletionDate` of type `DateTime?`. If your page model is a collection `IList<PrevMaintenanceList>` then each loop iteration would be `@Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].CompletionDate)`

Comment: I made it an `IList<PrevMaintenanceList>` For the three items it puts in 3 `CompletionDate` Edit boxes for each record. Although it allows me to pick dates for each box.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19965039/2030565

Comment: Use `EditorTemplate` for multiple input controls with model binding, ensuring that you have `@model IEnumerable<PrevMaintenanceList>` directive you can use `@Html.EditorFor(item => item[i].CompletionDate)`. Note that indexed properties can only be used by collection properties, not structs.

Comment: I researched it however I am not sure how to implement the `EditorTemplate` in an `Index` view. Can you point me to an example?