# MVC Controller List in model not binding

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an action in my MVC Controller

```
public FileStreamResult CustomerOrdersAsExcel(ExcelColumn column)
```

ExcelColumn model :

```
public class ExcelColumn
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public List<EnumLocalized> EnumLocalizations { get; set; }
}
```

then I use ajax to pass my ExcelColumn

```
let ajaxSettings = {
    type: 'GET',
    xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' },
    data: column,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: (data) => {
        ... on success
        }
    }
};
```

Column is object that has

```
"{"header":"Order type",
  "enumLocalizations":[ 
   {  
      "key":1,
      "value":"Customer order"
   },
   {  
      "key":2,
      "value":"Webshop"
   },
   {  
      "key":4,
      "value":"Service order"
   }
]}"
```

Now when I receive data in my controller Header is bound ok, but EnumLocalizations is not.
It has 3 elements where each element is filled with default value Key = 0 and Value = null.
I have tried to JSON.stringfy this and using traditional: true for jquery settings but neither of that worked.
Do you know what may cause that binding fail?

UPDATE: 
I think the error is in sent format by jquery which is

```
header:Order type
enumLocalizations[0][key]:1
enumLocalizations[0][value]:Customer order
enumLocalizations[1][key]:2
enumLocalizations[1][value]:Webshop
enumLocalizations[2][key]:4
enumLocalizations[2][value]:Service order
```

I think it should be something like

```
header:Order type
enumLocalizations[0].key:1
enumLocalizations[0].value:Customer order
enumLocalizations[1].key:2
enumLocalizations[1].value:Webshop
enumLocalizations[2].key:4
enumLocalizations[2].value:Service order
```

Do you know how can I change that?

Comment: Have you try declaring `EnumLocalizations` as `array` like `public EnumLocalized[] EnumLocalizations` ?

Comment: Collections should be bound in a different way, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964553/mvc-form-not-able-to-post-list-of-objects

Comment: @Andrei yep I edited my question, I think that my format is wrong, do you know how can I send this data with correct format?

Comment: You can't use `GET` to send object in body data, use `POST`. let me know if it worked

Comment: @Dabbas ok will let you know :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Dabbas said, change the ajax method to `POST` for sending big data (max url length is 255 characters), and don't use JSON to bind data, it's not necessary.

Try that, if didn't work, i'll remove :

```
var obj = {
    "header":"Order type",
    "enumLocalizations":[ 
         {  
          "key":1,
          "value":"Customer order"
         },
         {  
          "key":2,
          "value":"Webshop"
         },
         {  
          "key":4,
          "value":"Service order"
         }
    ]
};

let ajaxSettings = {
    type: 'POST',
    xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' },
    data: obj,
    success: (data) => {
        ... on success
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `GET` to send big amount of data, use `POST` instead.
`GET` will send all data through URL ([which is limited to about 2000 characters depending on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers))

```
let ajaxSettings = {
    type: 'POST',
    xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' },

    dataType: 'json',

    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: (data) => {
        ... on success
        }
    }
};
```