# Problems rendering a collection of items in controls without duplicate IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I'm populating an HTML table with a collection of data items.

But I want each cell to be editable. And so I'm displaying the item fields in controls. For example:

```
@foreach (FleetRailcarDto railcar in editSection.Railcars)
{
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <select asp-for="@railcar.FleetId" asp-items="@Model.FleetOptions" class="form-control-sm edit-fleet-id">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select asp-for="@railcar.Ownership" asp-items="@Model.OwnershipOptions" class="form-control-sm edit-ownership">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input asp-for="@railcar.CarType" class="form-control-sm edit-cartype" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This displays fine but it generates the same ID attributes for every table row.

I know I can build the HTML manually, but there are a few things going on here. Has anyone found a way to use `asp-for` for variations of the same property without causing duplicate ID attributes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375800/model-binding-to-a-list-mvc-4 If you use the HtmlHelper functions then it will automatically generate correct html with field ids and names like "question_0_1", "question_1_1" etc  `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Questions[i])`

Comment: @Charles: Thanks but I'm not sure that would help. First off, it's not an array. It's an `IEnumerable<>`. Also, I'm using Razor Pages and not MVC.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59096797/11808788
It works the same in asp.net core, if you use the Html Helper functions (for your selects) in a for loop with index access then the correct html will be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding to a collection for editing, you should use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop to iterate the collection. That way you generate an indexer to group fields together. You also need a hidden field set to the identity value of each item:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < editSection.Railcars.Count;i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" asp=for="editSection.Railcars[i].Id" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select asp-for="@editSection.Railcars[i].FleetId" asp-items="@Model.FleetOptions" class="form-control-sm edit-fleet-id">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select asp-for="@editSection.Railcars[i].Ownership" asp-items="@Model.OwnershipOptions" class="form-control-sm edit-ownership">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input asp-for="@editSection.Railcars[i].CarType" class="form-control-sm edit-cartype" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

More info here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections

Comment: The hidden field is not necessary unless you need to track the ID or other non-editable property.

Comment: I kind of assumed you would want to track the ID so that you can determine which entry to edit in the database, but if you have got it working, that's great.