# Why is my asp.net core razor pages model always empty in the OnPostAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

The goal is to populate a model using `OnGet()` and display the results of all records in a table and finally, be able to change only the state of the checkbox on multiple records and then submit the changes to `OnPostAsync()`.

The `.cshtml` page loads with all data from the database as expected. Existing records reflect the current checkbox state. But, I am not able to successfully post checkbox changes.

My issue is that the model is always empty (count = 0) in the `OnPostAsync()`. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, but I just can't figure it out or find a similar post that solves the problem.

I have researched and can't find a similar scenario or code sample that I can modify to fit my case.

`.cshtml.cs`:

```
[Authorize()]
public class OverviewModel : PageModel
{
     private readonly IAircraftModelsRepository aircraftModelsRepository;

     [BindProperty]
     public List<AllAircraftModels> listAircraftModels { get; set; }

     public OverviewModel(IAircraftModelsRepository aircraftModelsRepository)
     {
         this.aircraftModelsRepository = aircraftModelsRepository;
     }

     public async Task OnGet()
     {
         listAircraftModels = (await aircraftModelsRepository.GetAsync())?.ToList();
     }

     public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
     {
         foreach (var aircraftModel in listAircraftModels)
         {
            // listAircraftModels count is always zero here....
    
             await aircraftModelsRepository.UpdateAsync(aircraftModel);
         }

         return RedirectToPage("/AircraftModel/Overview");
     }
}
```

`.cshtml`:

```
@if (Model.listAircraftModels != null && Model.listAircraftModels.Any())
{
    <form method="post">
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>Mfg</td>
                        <td>Make</td>
                        <td>Model</td>
                        <td>Size Category</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var aircraftModel in Model.listAircraftModels)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="@aircraftModel.isChecked"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @aircraftModel.mfg
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @aircraftModel.make
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @aircraftModel.model
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @aircraftModel.sizeCategory
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input class="btn btn-dark me-2" type="submit"  value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <div class="container">
        <p>No aircraft models found!</p>
    </div>
}
```

`AllAircraftModels` class:

```
public class AllAircraftModels
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int modelId { get; set; }
    public string mfg { get; set; }
    public string make { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string sizeCategory { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924249/asp-net-core-3-mvc-model-binding-of-a-list-of-objects

Comment: Thanks for the suggested answers. I have made some progress, but ran into a new AntiforgeryValidationException if I try to use more than one <input> in the table. .cshtml has been updated to show changes. I tried @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in the table and also [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] for the OnPostAsync() suggested in some other answers.

Comment: Please ask a new question for that - we try to keep each question to a single focused topic, and not change it when the first issue is resolved. You can accept the suggested duplicate if it resolved your original problem.