# ASP.NET MVC: post a list to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC application, the model is a list of objects. It is used in the view like this:

```
<h4>Order Acknowledgement Contact(s)</h4>

@foreach (var contact in Model.Where(c => c.Type == "AK").Take(3))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(c => contact.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => contact.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}

<h4>Shipping Acknowledgement Contact(s)</h4>

@foreach (var contact in Model.Where(c => c.Type == "BK").Take(3))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(c => contact.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => contact.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When the form is submitted, in the controller the List is null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(List<CustomerContact> customerContacts)
    {
```

Is it possible to fix binding and preserve using linq etc?

Comment: You could create a form per entry you wish to show, or you could keep a hidden index and post the entire list.

Comment: @CodeCaster Everything should be posted at once. But every entry is identified by two values (Type and LineNumber), both are in CustomerContact, and Email is the value that is being edited. How can it be used?

Comment: As I use linq rather than for loop, how can I even have the index?

Comment: You need an index on your inputs to bind a posted collection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964553/mvc-form-not-able-to-post-list-of-objects

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "preserve using linq".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach loop never submits items back to the controller, it can only display items. So you should use only for loop.

So it is a good idea to create a viewmodel

```
public class ViewModel
{
public List<CustomerContact>  Aks {get; set;}
public List<CustomerContact>  Bks {get; set;}

{
```

your get action

```
var model =  new ViewModel
{
 Aks= contacts.Where(c => c.Type == "AK").Take(3));
 Bks= contacts.Where(c => c.Type == "BK").Take(3));
}
 ....
return View(model);
```

post action

```
    public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel model)
```

and finally view

```
@model ViewModel

.....
for (var i=0; i< Model.Aks; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Aks[i].Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Aks[i].Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}

.... the same for model.Bks
```

Comment: Great, thank you!