# How to pass multiple objects of same model type from view to controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, model-binding

I am working in ASP.NET MVC 5 and am trying to post a form back to the controller. The form basically has several repeating textboxes that . I am trying to reuse the one model for each repeating form so I don't have to make a new field for each text box there is.

Model:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The part of my view where I am model binding text boxes (this is under `@html.beginform`)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PeronSave", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "PersonForm" })) 
<td>Person 1</td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })  </td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { @class = "form-control" })  </td>
```

Now I want to have several of these groups of text boxes, so there would be Person1, Person2, Person3 etc. Is there a way I can send a list of type Person back to the controller?

I have tried changing using a foreach loop in the view but it doesn't have the desired result.

Comment: You can post a list of objects with an index `Name[0]`. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/19964553/2030565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass list of type of Person to the backend, You need to add index to each property. Please refer to this simple demo:

Here I use @for(xx)  to create three Person inputs and add index to each property:

```
@model List<Person>

@using (Html.BeginForm("PeronSave", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "PersonForm" }))
{
    @for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        <td>Person @(i+1)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Name, new { @class = "form-control" })  </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Age, new { @class = "form-control" })  </td>
    }

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
}
```

**The Page looks like:**

[image]

**Then I pass it to the backend and the controller can receive data successfully.**

[image]

Comment: Hey I found this after I posted yesterday but thank you for the answer as it does work, I have marked it.